# Calling methods for draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have this code for a page with draggable divs.  Initially, I had the first two lines of the code, to make the divs draggable and to specify a drag handle.  Then I needed to add a helper function to clone the draggable.  When I added the helper function, it broke the code.  The divs weren't draggable anymore.  What is it about the way I wrote the code that might explain this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#".$url['ID'].".link').draggable();
  $('#".$url['ID'].".link').draggable('option', 'handle', '.link_handle');
  $('#".$url['ID'].".link').draggable({
       helper: function(){ 
                 $copy = $(this).clone();
                 $(this).remove();
                 return $copy;
              }, 
       appendTo: 'body', 
       scroll: false 
  });
</script>
```

I found that if I have `.draggable();` and then another call `.draggable({});`, that second call breaks the draggable behavior.  Since I am new to this, there must be a basic issue with structuring the code that way.

UPDATE

The draggables are created by a php script called like this.

```
  <div id="page"> <!-- Begin page div -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
               // Make ajax call to recreate linkcards from XML data
               $.ajax({
                   url: "get_nodes.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: { },
                   cache: false,
                   success: function (response) {
                       if (response != '') 
                       {
                          $("#page").append(response);                 
                       }
                   }
               });
    });
    </script>

  </div> <!-- End page div -->
```

This is the code in get_nodes.php that creates the draggables.

```
<?php

function get_nodes() {
// load SimpleXML
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('linkcards.xml', null, true);

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{
        // Add LinkCard
        echo "<div id = '".$node['ID']."' class= 'linkcard ui-widget-content' style = 'top: ".$node->TOP."px; left: ".$node->LEFT."px; width: ".$node->WIDTH."px; height: ".$node->HEIGHT."px;'> \n";

        echo "   <p class = 'linkcard_header editableText'>".$node->NAME."</p>\n";

        echo "   <div class='toolbar'> <a href='#' title='Options' class='ico_tools'></a> <a href='#' title='Delete' class='ico_delete' onClick=\"delete_linkcard('".$node['ID']."');\"></a> </div>\n";

        echo "   <div class='link_drop_box'>\n";

        // Add links
        foreach($node->LINKS->LINK as $url)
        { 
           $urlico = substr($url->URL,7);

           // Add link with tools
           echo ' <div id="'.$url['ID'].'" class="link"> <img class="link_handle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='.$urlico.'" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="'.$url->URL.'" target="_blank" onmouseOver="preview_link(\'show\', this, \''.$node['ID'].'\');" onmouseOut="preview_link(\'hide\', this, \''.$node['ID'].'\');" >'.$url->TITLE.'</a> <a title="Edit" class="link_button_edit" href="#" onClick=""></a><a title="Delete" class="link_button_delete" href="#" onClick="delete_link(\''.$url['ID'].'\', \''.$node['ID'].'\');"> </a> </div>';

             // Make link draggable
             echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
             echo "  $('#".$url['ID'].".link').draggable({ 
                     handle: '.link_handle', 
                     helper: function() {  
                           $copy = $(this).clone(); 
                           $(this).remove(); 
                           return $copy; 
                     },  
                     appendTo: 'body' ,  
                     scroll: false 
                     }); \n";
             echo "</script>\n";       
        }

        echo "</div> \n";

        // Add scrolling buttons
        echo '<div class="scrolling_prev" title="Previous"></div>';
        echo '<div class="scrolling_next" title="Next"></div>';

        // Add LinkCard tools
        echo "   <div class='tools' > <a href='#' title='Add Link' class='ico_add' onClick=\"add_link('".$node['ID']."');\"></a> <a href='#' title='Search Links' class='ico_search' onClick=\"open_search('".$node['ID']."');\"></a> </div>\n";

        echo '  <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    $(document).ready(function($) {
                       $(".scrolling_prev", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).mousedown(function() {
                            startScrolling($(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")), "-=50px");
                        }).mouseup(function() {
                            $(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).stop()
                        });
                        $(".scrolling_next", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).mousedown(function() {
                            startScrolling($(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")), "+=50px");
                        }).mouseup(function() {
                            $(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).stop();
                        });
                    });
                </script>';

        echo "</div> \n";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').resizable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable('option', 'handle', '.linkcard_header');\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable({ stop: function(event, ui) { update_linkcard_xml('".$node['ID']."') } });\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo '  $("#'.$node['ID'].' '.CHR(46).'link_drop_box" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                var $item = ui.draggable;
                $item.fadeOut(function() {
                     $item.css( {"left":"", "top":"", "bottom":"", "right":"" }).fadeIn();
                });
                $item.appendTo( this );
            },
            out: function( event, ui ) {
            },
            accept: ".link",
        });';
        echo "</script>\n";

}
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('.editableText').editableText();\n";                              
        echo "</script>\n";

   return;
}

echo get_nodes();


?>
```

UPDATE 10/24/2011

Draggable specified like this echoes in the PHP response.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo "  $('#".$url['ID'].".link').draggable();\n";
echo "</script>\n";
```

Draggable specified like this breaks the PHP response.  No information is returned from the code.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo '  $("#'.$url['ID'].'.link").draggable({
             handle: ".link_handle", 
             helper: function() {  
                $copy = $(this).clone();
                $(this).remove();
                return $copy; 
             },
             appendTo: "body" ,
             scroll: false 
         }); \n';
echo "</script>\n";
```

If I put each line in a separate echo statement, it doesn't help.  Is there a better way to send that statement to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine the options:

```
$('#".$url['ID'].".link').draggable({
    handle: '.link_handle',
    helper: function() { 
        $copy = $(this).clone();
        $(this).remove();
        return $copy;
    }, 
    appendTo: 'body', 
    scroll: false 
});
```

=== UPDATE ===

I have made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5r6ym/). Here all options work:

- `handle`: you can only drag the div by clicking the blue div
- `appendTo`: the draggable helper's container during dragging is the body
- `scroll`: the container auto-scrolls while dragging is disabled (turn it on to see the different)
- `helper`: in the example there are four draggables, each with a different `helper` option:

  - `original`: the original div will be dragged
  - `clone`: a clone will be displayed while dragging
  - `function 1`: your helper function without the removing does the same as the `clone` option
  - `function 2`: your helper function removes the original draggable and displays a clone while dragging

Comment: That did not fix the problem.  The element doesn't seem draggable with that code.  Doesn't seem to like the helper, appendto, and scroll options.

Comment: Thanks.  Everything works in the jsfiddle.  The different tests help with what I am trying to do.  But I am still having a problem with my code.  The javascript is echoed into the html when the page is loaded.  This has happened before where the echoed script doesn't do what the script would if it where in the HTML page.  I am updating the question to show you how I call the code.  Maybe you can tell why it doesn't do what it should.  It works for draggable but not for the other options.

Comment: In the php file you can remove the `return;` and replace the `echo get_nodes();` with `get_nodes();`. But this will not solve your problem. Because I can't see the problem without testing, can you explain exactly what happens? What is ok, what's not? It would be very helpfull, if you can post the ajax response. Maybe you have a link, where I can test it?

Comment: The echo statement where the draggable is cloned isn't echoed at all in the php response.  I put the statement in the update.  The code breaks on that statement.

Comment: The code works better now.  There must have been a problem with the quotes/double quotes.  Now the clone is created.  But when I drop it unto the second container, that container has the clone and the original.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call draggable() once per element you are making draggable. Any other calls will basically overwrite the previous draggable functionality. Check out the examples on the [jquery ui site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Comment: Are you saying that I should have `.draggable ({'option',...}, {helper: function(){}});`